# Worpress url parse

Tags: url-rewriting, get-posts, parse

I want to display posts in certain category only with given tag. Problem with parsing url slugs.

For example, I have category named 'Clothes':

example.com/clothes/

I can get posts in this category with tag 'red' by getting url parameters, like that:

example.com/clothes/?tag=red

But I want to use slugs for that, no get parameters. Examples:

example.com/clothes/tag/red

example.com/clothes/tag/large

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `add_rewrite_rule()` method, or `add_rewrite_endpoint()` in order to flush rewrite rules, and links you must generate with `add_query_arg()` method for ugly urls, for tiny u must simple concatenate with permalink